# Android Retorifit - event on every item of list read

Tags: android, retrofit2

Dears,
I would like to achieve ProgressBar showing percentage number of items already loaded, when reading JSON response from REST endpoint.
I'm using Retrofit2 library for reading JSON response with some converters and it works fine, but the Response is of `Response<List<Item>>`, so the processing of the Response within the onResponse() method starts, when the whole list is already read and parsed.
My idea was to obtain some "onSingleItemsRead" event from Retrofit and apply listener to this event, which would then call the ProgressBar to show the number of items already read (I have also prepared REST call finding number of all items in the list before reading the list itself). But I cannot find any event, which would allow that. What would be the best approach to achieve that?

Comment: That is not possible. What I can decipher from your question is you're getting your entire dataset in one call. Now to solve your query, you need to make multiple API calls (if it is possible) to get each item one at a time and update the progressbar as the items get received on onResponse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your fast answer. Yes, the whole dataset is called at once. As it is my own API, it will be probably possible to make it Pageable for example and read it by smaller pieces.

Comment: You're welcome! (: You will probably have to make chained retrofit API calls, if you're not familiar with them, make sure you take a quick look!